# SSO SAML SP - How many websites to cover under one SP?

Tags: asp.net, saml, kentor-authservices

I'm attempting to implement a saml service provider, but i'm not sure what level of system to cover with a single SP.

What level of architecture per SP is considered good practice? Should we have one for our entire department, per server, per domain, per application pool or even for every site?

Our organisation has a shibboleth IDP and i'm using kentor authservices. Its working for one site but the sp is part of that site. 
Assuming best practice is not one per-site if anyone has a hint on how best to approach making it more generic (i.e. one entityid for multiple sites) that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you need to get the login information into each site/application. Either you use an SP per site (which is the Kentor.AuthServices approach) or you set up a Shibboleth SP proxy in front of the web apps. The latter means you have to add code to each site to parse the http headers that Shibboleth delivers. I don't like that approach - that's why I started the Kentor.AuthServices project.

So, my preference is to have make each site a proper SP through a module that is as native as possible for the web application framework. Modules that might be relevant are Kentor.AuthServices (.NET), SimpleSamlPhp, Spring (Java), saml2-js (node).

In the case that you organisation have multiple sites/applications that you want to federate with multiple upstream Identity Providers you will get NxM pairs of configuration, which is not scalable. An option in that case is to insert a SAML2 *proxy* that acts as Idp to your internal applications and as SP to the external Idps. New sites/applications only need to be configured in the proxy and new external Idps only need to be configured in the proxy.